# How do I write this CTE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, rdbms, common-table-expression

Hello I want to Update 1 table based on value present in other table. I could use Join to write the update statement and infact I have written it and it works using Join. But out of curiosity I want to use CTE. I wrote the following query but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody tell me what the issue is? Does CTE require Select statement at the end compulsorily? Why can I not write Update statement?

```
WITH cte(uid, col1)
As
(
    Select uid, col1
        From [User]
)
Update t2
    Set col1 = cte.col1
        Where uid = cte.uid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to join back to your CTE, like so

```
WITH cte([uid], col1)
As
(
    Select [uid], col1
        From [User]
)
Update t2
    Set col1 = cte.col1
    FROM t2 inner join cte cte 
    on t2.[uid] = cte.[uid]
```

**Edit** I guess you could avoid the 'JOIN' keyword  by using [old-style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) SQL WHERE joins, but this isn't really good practice.

```
...        
FROM t2, cte cte 
WHERE t2.[uid] = cte.[uid]
```

Also note that you can also update through the CTE, like views, as long as you only update one table.

```
WITH cte(userCol1, t2Col1)
As
(
    Select [u].col1 as userCol1, t2.col1 as t2Col1
        From [User] u
        inner join t2
         ON u.[uid] = t2.[uid]
)
Update cte
    Set t2Col1 = userCol1
```

Comment: Oh if that is the case I could just omit the CTE and write a simple update with JOIN.